# jQuery vs CSS3: Infinite background loop

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Say you have a background image which will loop infinitely, I see that with CSS3 that simple animation consumes up to 50% of my PC memory, which is a lot, haven't tried with jQuery though.

What are your thoughts? Which one consumes less PC memory?

Here's my Webkit CSS3 code:

```
.stars_back {
    background: url('stars.png') repeat; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: -10;
    -webkit-animation-name: star-back; -webkit-animation-duration: 1700s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes star-back {
    from { background-position: 1000% 5% }
    to { background-position: 5% 5% }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Animating background images is not efficient, it doesn't matter if it's jQuery or CSS transitions. I'd suggest you to add an extra element which contains the background image to apply hardware acceleration:

```
.stars_back {
    /* right: 100% forces the div to be twice the intended width, parent should have overflow: hidden */
    background: url('stars.png') repeat; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 100%; bottom: 0; z-index: -10;
    -webkit-animation-name: star-back; -webkit-animation-duration: 1700s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes star-back {
    /* translate3d(-50%,0,0) puts the second half of the div in the viewport and then repeats*/
    from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) }
    to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0) }
}
```